# Getting names of all files in a directory

Tags: file, directory, scheme, racket

I can easily get a list of all files (including subdirectories) in a directory using the command

```
(directory-list)
```

But the output is in following form:

```
'(#<path:afile> #<path:bfile.txt> #<path:thirdfile.doc>)
```

How can I convert this to a simple list of strings of file names as follows:

```
'("afile" "bfile.txt" "thirdfile.doc")
```

I tried following but it does not work:

```
(map string (directory-list))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `path->string`, eg

```
(map path->string (directory-list))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Can I get names of full path (i.e. including the directory name)?

Comment: @mso you could use `(map path->string (directory-list #:build? #t))`